# Sistema de post

Tags: php, mysqli

acho que o título n ficou muito claro mas vou explicar certinho aqui o que necessito e não estou obtendo resultados bons.

Bom o que estou tentando fazer é o seguinte.

No link da minha página ela fica dessa forma -> " www.site.com/Teste?cadastro=1 "

Esse valor " 1 " é o ID, até ai tudo bem, mas o que eu queria é outro campo do meu banco de dados como por exemplo o campo Código.

Fazendo com que esse link fique dessa forma -> "www.site.com/Teste?cadastro=A1g667100B"

Esse é meu código.

```
<?php
    $Pagina = (isset($_GET['Codigo'])) ? $_GET['Codigo'] : 1;
    $BancoD = "SELECT * FROM cadastro ORDER BY id ASC";

    $Val = mysqli_query($conexao,$BancoD);
    $Total = mysqli_num_rows($Val);
    $Quantidade = 1;
    $NumeroPagina = ceil($Total/$Quantidade);
    $PaginaInicial = ($Quantidade*$Pagina)-$Quantidade;

    $Bancod = "SELECT * FROM cadastro ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $PaginaInicial,$Quantidade";
    $Val= mysqli_query($conexao,$BancoD);
    $Total = mysqli_num_rows($Val);

    while ($NovelPost = mysqli_fetch_array($Val)){
        echo $NovelPost['Nome'];
        echo $NovelPost['Idade'];
        echo $NovelPost['Cidade'];
        echo $NovelPost['Codigo'];              
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso você vai fazer assim:

www.site.com/Teste?cadastro=1&codigo=A1g667100B

Mas sugiro a você começar a aprender o método post também, caso este dado seja de sigilo. Se não for, pode pegar via GET sem problema.
Muito cuidado com informações no GET.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica do Post, Mas no caso do link, ainda ficaria mostrando o Número 1, o que quero é que o link fique apenas com o código sem o número do ID.

Comment: Neste caso é justamente por que você está enviando no seu formulário pelo método GET. Mude para method='POST' no form do seu html que ele envia sem colocar nada lá. Mas, altere também seu PHP para POST ao invés de GET para pegar os dados.